# How to use DropdownButton inside a loop?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can add more than one DropdownButton dynamically according to a data. But I can't reach the value values despite trying everything. Can you help me what should I do about this?

I am doing the listing process with the code below.

```dart
List getAttribute = [];
  List selectAttribute = [];
  Future getAllAttribuList() async {
    final attributeList = await deviceAttributeList(context, selectModel);
    if (attributeList != null) {
      setState(() {
        getAttribute = attributeList;
      });
    }
  }
```

Here is the error I get on the device
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGCje_5GTb8

```
value: selectAttribute.length > 0 ? selectAttribute[index] : null,
```

Here I am creating a widget and listing it below. How do I find value when I select DropdownButton value?

```dart
  List<Widget> getAttrList() {
    List<Widget> childs = [];
    childs = getAttribute.map((item) {
      if (getAttribute.isNotEmpty) {
        List options = item.options;
        var index = getAttribute.indexOf(item);
        print('Data Index ${index}');
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: selectAttribute.length > 0 ? selectAttribute[index] : null,
              hint: Text(item.name.toString()),
              items: options.map(
                (map) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(map.name),
                    value: map.id.toString(),
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectAttribute.add(value);
                });
              },
              underline: const SizedBox()),
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    }).toList();
    return childs;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.

```dart
List<Widget> getAttrList() {
    List<Widget> childs = [];
    childs = getAttribute.map((item) {
      if (getAttribute.isNotEmpty) {
        List options = item.options;
        var index = getAttribute.indexOf(item);
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: selectAttribute.length > 0
                  ? selectAttribute.asMap().containsKey(index)
                      ? selectAttribute[index]
                      : null
                  : null,
              hint: Text(item.name.toString()),
              items: options.map(
                (map) {
                  var optionIndex = selectAttribute.indexOf(map);
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(map.name),
                    value: map.id.toString(),
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    print(selectAttribute);
                    //selectAttribute[index]!.add(value);
                    if (selectAttribute.asMap().containsKey(index)) {
                      selectAttribute.removeAt(index);
                    }
                    //selectAttribute.removeAt(index);
                    selectAttribute.insert(index, value);
                    print(selectAttribute);
                  });
                }
              },
              underline: const SizedBox()),
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    }).toList();
    return childs;
  }
```